# How do I bind Data from my DataTable to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I will elaborate. I am trying to get a description for a failed payment and I want to hover over the image or Status to see the reason description for the failed payment:

Here is the c# to get the Data bound to the Gridview

```
DataTable BillingDT = new DataTable();

BillingDT = Q.GetBillHistory(SessionVars.Current.varContractID);
BillingDT.Columns.Add("PayNum", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
BillingDT.Columns.Add("DateStr", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
BillingDT.Columns.Add("AmountStr", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
BillingDT.Columns.Add("BalanceStr", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
BillingDT.Columns.Add("description", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

string DownPayment = DT.Select("Name = 'DownPayment'")[0][1].ToString();

for (int row = 0; row < BillingDT.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    BillingDT.Rows[row]["PayNum"] = BillingDT.Rows[row]["Payment"].ToString();
    BillingDT.Rows[row]["DateStr"] = Convert.ToDateTime(BillingDT.Rows[row]["paydate"]).ToShortDateString();

    if (BillingDT.Rows[row]["payment"].ToString() == "0") { 
        BillingDT.Rows[row]["PayNum"] = DownPayment; 
    }

    if (BillingDT.Rows[row]["status"].ToString().Length < 1) {
        BillingDT.Rows[row]["status"] = "";
    }

    if (BillingDT.Rows[row]["descript"].ToString().Length < 1) {
        BillingDT.Rows[row]["description"] = "";
    }

    if (BillingDT.Rows[row]["amount"].ToString().Length > 0) { 
        BillingDT.Rows[row]["AmountStr"] = FV.MoneyString(Convert.ToDecimal(BillingDT.Rows[row]["amount"])); 
    }

    BillingDT.Rows[row]["BalanceStr"] = (BillingDT.Rows[row]["balance"].ToString().Length > 0) ? FV.MoneyString(Convert.ToDecimal(BillingDT.Rows[row]["balance"])) : "";
}

BillingHistoryGV.DataSource = BillingDT;
BillingHistoryGV.DataBind();
```

and here is the ASP:Image that I want to bind the description to the Tooltip:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="StatusIconImg" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage((string)Eval("Status")) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="20px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, would you not just have to bind the `ToolTip` property of your image? `ToolTip='<%# Eval("description") %>'`

```
<asp:Image ID="StatusIconImg" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage((string)Eval("Status")) %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
```

Comment: my problem was using "description" instead of just using the field "descript" which was coming from the SQL table. It is working now!! thanks